# How to set user-specific HDFS trash intervals?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've seen that you can edit the trash interval on HDFS in the core-site.xml file.

This looks like these configurations apply to all users. Is there a way to set a specific trash interval for a certain user? The default works for most accounts but I'd like to be specific with others.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set a specific trash interval for a certain user?

**No.**

HDFS Trash is a cluster level feature and its properties `fs.trash.interval` and `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval` applies to the entire filesystem.